# How to create a local web server anonymously?

Tags: apache2, webserver, ip, anonymous-methods, tor

I have a local web server using Apache2 and people can access it just having my external IP address. What I wanna do is to use some IP else so that way I will need to pass the false IP to my visitor and he will connect to my web server through that false-IP. Is it possible in any way to do it freely using something like TOR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using Tor's hidden services is that the client needs to install Tor and then enter a funky.onion address.

It really depends on what the goal of this obfuscation is.  If the goal is to hide the server, then Tor is the best way to do that.

However, taking the question literally, if a false IP address is all that is needed, you would use the [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html) command on a fake apache server.  For instance,

> Redirect /docs/ http://new.example.com/docs/

You could even have two IP addresses on the same server, but this kind of makes me wonder what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Tor Hidden services :

https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en